# nodejs - cannot use module from imported package

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I create an npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-top-down-test, which just exports two objects `VueTopDown` and `VueTopDownItem`.

```
import { VueTopDown } from './vue-top-down'
import { VueTopDownItem } from './vue-top-down-item'

module.exports = {
  VueTopDown,
  VueTopDownItem
}
```

However, I failed to use (even just print) them in my demo https://github.com/MoYummy/vue-top-down/tree/master/docs/demo-node.

```
import * as VTD from 'vue-top-down-test'
import Vue from 'vue'

console.log(Vue)
console.log(VTD)
```

Could anybody give me some clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally make it: https://github.com/MoYummy/vue-top-down/tree/v0.0.1

The key is to build `commonjs`, `umd` and `esm` for each runtime environment.

npm: https://unpkg.com/vue-top-down@0.0.1/dist/

use: https://moyummy.github.io/vue-top-down/example/

Answer (score 0):

Set `output.libraryTarget` as `umd` in your **webpack.config.js**. Default `libraryTarget` is set `var`. The return value is assigned to a variable, it cannot be used inside module

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'VueTopDown',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  }
```

**Multiple target**
Although webpack does not support multiple strings being passed into the target property, you can create an isomorphic library by bundling two separate configurations: [Multiple Targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets)

```
const path = require('path');
const serverConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'lib.node.js'
  }
  //…
};

const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web', // <=== can be omitted as default is 'web'
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'lib.js'
  }
  //…
};

module.exports = [ serverConfig, clientConfig ];
```

Modified `webpack.config.js` for your reference

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const serverConfig = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: {
    'vue-top-down': './src/index.js',
    'vue-top-down.min': './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'VueTopDown',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['env']
      }
    }]
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.min\.js$/
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    ]),
  ]
};

const clientConfig = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'web',
  entry: {
    'vue-top-down': './src/index.js',
    'vue-top-down.min': './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].web.js',
    library: 'VueTopDown'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['env']
      }
    }]
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.min\.js$/
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    ]),
  ]
};

module.exports = [serverConfig, clientConfig];
```

Comment: Great, thanks! But call in browser will fail: `https://moyummy.github.io/vue-top-down/docs/demo-browser-script.html`. Do I need to build separate two js?

Comment: Updated answer for multiple target